# Python: time data does not match format

Tags: python, datetime, time, format, match

When I run the code, I get this error:

> ValueError: time data '2021-10-26T10:15:00.000+04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

The format seems to be correct, what's the problem? Does anyone had the same problem?

I'm using this method

```
# Convert 2019-09-03T12:31:03.806+0400 to 2019-09-13 16:30:12
def time_converter(time):
    if time is None:
        time = ''
    else:
        time_obj = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        time = time_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return time
```

I just give it time in this format `2021-10-26T10:15:00.000+04:00`

Comment: This works for me in python 3.8 `datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-10-26T10:15:00.000+04:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')`

Comment: @shotikoj, please post the actual code you're having the problem with.

Comment: could you please add your Python version?

Answer (score 0):

You code worked for me without error, but in your Python version you may need to replace ':' with '' in time zone:

2021-10-26T10:15:00.000+**04:00**
2019-09-03T12:31:03.806+**0400**

Comment: you could add on option *how* to replace the right-most `:`, for example `'2021-10-26T10:15:00.000+04:00'[::-1].replace(':','',1)[::-1]`.

Comment: from the official doc: "Changed in version 3.7: When the %z directive is provided to the strptime() method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds."

Answer (score 0):

Problem was With Python Version. Remote Server Where the code was running had Python 3.6. As tromgy commented here, %z directive was added in 3.7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, shotioj. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You don't have to post an answer just to confirm that the other answer was indeed correct. Instead accept the answer that best helped you (and/or upvote it).

Comment: On second thought, this might be a corner case, since tromgy only posted a comment and the other answer did not include a full solution either. Maybe you could expand your answer a bit to include all relevant information and add a working solution. That could make this a good answer :-)